# Issues in Training Custom Named Entity Recogniser in Apache OpenNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp, training-data, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to build a custom NER model to extract Indian names. However I lack training data (I only have the list of names).

So I thought of creating my own corpus, using each name to be replaced in the following lines

```
Hi How are you <START:person> Hardik <END> 
<START:person> Hardik <END>  is a great personality
Contributions from <START:person> Hardik <END>  are very important
<START:person> Hardik <END>  believes in honesty
Meek and tidy soul, <START:person> Hardik <END> derives happiness from all opportunities.
```

I do this for each of 3000 names that I have and hence end up with a corpus of around 15K.

However now when I try to run my code, using this as my test data

```
This employment is for Hardik
```

I end up getting an output like this

```
[0..1) person  This
[1..2) person  employment
[2..3) person  is
[3..4) person  for
[4..5) person  Hardik
```

Each word in the document is thrown as `person`. Is this an example of `overfitting/noise`. I am really confused here as to why is it behaving like this even when the words are not annotated like that